# What steps do I need to take to make Kafka and Flink work on EMR without getting 'The AdminClient thread has exited. Call: describeTopics' error?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, amazon-emr, pyflink

I am trying to use a kafka source in with the pyflink table API as follows:

```
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.INFO, format="%(message)s")

env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()
env.set_parallelism(1)

env.add_jars("file:///opt/flink/lib/flink-sql-connector-kafka-1.16.0.jar",
             "file:///opt/flink/lib/flink-sql-connector-elasticsearch7-1.16.0.jar",
             "file:///opt/flink/lib/flink-sql-avro-1.16.0.jar",
             "file:///opt/flink/lib/flink-sql-avro-confluent-registry-1.16.0.jar")

t_env = StreamTableEnvironment.create(stream_execution_environment=env)
t_env.get_config().get_configuration().set_boolean("python.fn-execution.memory.managed", True)

create_kafka_source_ddl = """
    CREATE TABLE KafkaTable (
            **TABLE DETAILS**
    WITH (
            'connector' = 'kafka',
            'scan.startup.mode' = 'latest-offset',

            'topic' = '**TOPIC NAME**',
            'properties.bootstrap.servers' = '**HOST:PORT**',
            'properties.group.id' = 'GROUP ID',

            'properties.security.protocol' = 'SASL_SSL',
            'properties.sasl.mechanism' = 'SCRAM-SHA-512',
            'properties.sasl.jaas.config' = 'org.apache.flink.kafka.shaded.org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule
                required
                username=\"**USERNAME**\"
                password=\"**PASSOWORD**\";',
            'properties.ssl.truststore.type' = 'PEM',
            'properties.ssl.truststore.location' = '**/PATH/TO/PEM**',
            **REST ARE FORMATTING DETAILS**

create_print_sink_ddl = """
        CREATE TABLE print_sink(
            id STRING,
            name STRING,
            country_code STRING
        ) with (
            'connector' = 'print'
        );
    """

t_env.execute_sql(create_kafka_source_ddl)
t_env.execute_sql(create_print_sink_ddl)

t_env.from_path("KafkaTable") \
    .select(col('id'), col('name'), col('country_code')) \
    .execute_insert("print_sink")
```

However, upon submission of this job to a flink cluster running on Amazon EMR, the job is instantly cancelled with the following error:

```
org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Recovery is suppressed by NoRestartBackoffTimeStrategy
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.handleFailure(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:139)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.getGlobalFailureHandlingResult(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:102)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.handleGlobalFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:299)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.coordination.OperatorCoordinatorHolder$LazyInitializedCoordinatorContext.lambda$failJob$0(OperatorCoordinatorHolder.java:635)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.lambda$handleRunAsync$4(AkkaRpcActor.java:453)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ClassLoadingUtils.runWithContextClassLoader(ClassLoadingUtils.java:68)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRunAsync(AkkaRpcActor.java:453)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:218)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:84)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:168)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:24)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:20)
    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse$(PartialFunction.scala:122)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:20)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:537)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:535)
    at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:220)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:580)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:548)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:270)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:231)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:243)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:175)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Global failure triggered by OperatorCoordinator for 'Source: KafkaTable[1] -> Calc[2] -> Sink: print_sink[3]' (operator cbc357ccb763df2852fee8c4fc7d55f2).
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.coordination.OperatorCoordinatorHolder$LazyInitializedCoordinatorContext.failJob(OperatorCoordinatorHolder.java:617)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.coordination.RecreateOnResetOperatorCoordinator$QuiesceableContext.failJob(RecreateOnResetOperatorCoordinator.java:237)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.source.coordinator.SourceCoordinatorContext.failJob(SourceCoordinatorContext.java:360)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.source.coordinator.SourceCoordinatorContext.handleUncaughtExceptionFromAsyncCall(SourceCoordinatorContext.java:373)
    at org.apache.flink.util.ThrowableCatchingRunnable.run(ThrowableCatchingRunnable.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkRuntimeException: Failed to list subscribed topic partitions due to 
    at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.enumerator.KafkaSourceEnumerator.checkPartitionChanges(KafkaSourceEnumerator.java:234)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.source.coordinator.ExecutorNotifier.lambda$null$1(ExecutorNotifier.java:83)
    at org.apache.flink.util.ThrowableCatchingRunnable.run(ThrowableCatchingRunnable.java:40)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to get metadata for topics [**TOPIC NAME**].
    at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.enumerator.subscriber.KafkaSubscriberUtils.getTopicMetadata(KafkaSubscriberUtils.java:47)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.enumerator.subscriber.TopicListSubscriber.getSubscribedTopicPartitions(TopicListSubscriber.java:52)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.enumerator.KafkaSourceEnumerator.getSubscribedTopicPartitions(KafkaSourceEnumerator.java:219)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.source.coordinator.ExecutorNotifier.lambda$notifyReadyAsync$2(ExecutorNotifier.java:80)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.flink.kafka.shaded.org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: The AdminClient thread has exited. Call: describeTopics
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1908)
    at org.apache.flink.kafka.shaded.org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:165)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.enumerator.subscriber.KafkaSubscriberUtils.getTopicMetadata(KafkaSubscriberUtils.java:44)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.kafka.shaded.org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: The AdminClient thread has exited. Call: describeTopics
```

This error does not happen when I run my code on my local machine. Can anybody point me in the right direction as to how to get a kafka consumer working on EMR? My kafka host is on DigitalOcean if that is helpful.

Comment: Are you able to run a normal Kafka console consumer successfully? If not, then Flink isn't the problem. Plus, you could use MSK to run Kafka in AWS rather than MSK, or you could try running Flink in DigitalOcean... Then you wouldn't have to debug many networking issues (such as your timeout error)

Comment: I have successfully run the kaf CLI to consume my topic on EMR, so I think that it's an issue with Flink. Yep, am asking to see if this is an issue with EMR <-> DigitalOcean compatibility, as migration to MSK may result in additional complexity (that I am open to, if all else fails).

Comment: It's possible there's a firewall / VPC config you're missing, or you simply need to increase the AdminClient timeout config, but the infrastructure themselves aren't "incompatible", no